# PHP visitor list array

Tags: php

I am currently working on my own shoutboxes using PHP, MYSQL and Jquery.

When a user has entered the shoutbox a message appears saying:

X has entered the shoutbox.

I do not want to store all visitors / users in MYSQL rows and so I was thinking I would need an array with a foreach script.

I'm not too sure how I should go about doing this, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: how are you currently holding the rows of the shoutbox, so if I come back later, the messages are still being shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `$_session` variable, like when a user entered the shoutbox `$_session->users[] = $user`. `$_session->users` should be an array where you keep only their ids.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you plan on storing this data in session?  Depending on how you have session configured on your server, you may still be storing this data in a database (although the development effort may be less as you won't have to roll your own SQL to manage state).

The PHP manual has a section on arrays that sounds like it would be worth your time to read:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.  The manual has examples of adding objects to the array as well as looping through an existing array.